# Calculating $P(A\cup B\ |\ C)$

Tags: probability

Does the inclusion-exclusion principle hold even for conditional probabilities? i.e. is it true that $$P(A\cup B\ |\ C)=P(A\ |\ C)+P(B\ |\ C)-P(A,B\ |\ C)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it holds.

This is equivalent to

$$\frac{P((A\cap C)\cup (B \cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)}+\frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(C)} - \frac{P(A \cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $P(C)>0$, then $P(\cdot|C)$ behaves just like any probability. (just a relativised measure, in a way, rescaled).